# SQL select distinct from a concatenated column

Tags: sql-server-2016

This query almost does what I want

```
SELECT staging.dbo.ITEM_CODES.ITEM_CODE, MAX(dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40) AS SAMPLEDATE,
           CONCAT(RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1), RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL6)) as LinkID
FROM dbo.OC_VDATA 
    INNER JOIN dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX ON dbo.OC_VDATA.PARTNO = dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX AND dbo.OC_VDATA.DATETIME = dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.DATETIMEAUX 
    INNER JOIN stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES ON LEFT(dbo.OC_VDATA.PARTNO, 12) = staging.dbo.ITEM_CODES.SPEC_NO 
    AND LEFT(dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX, 12) = stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.SPEC_NO 
    INNER JOIN stagingPLM.dbo.PLANTS ON dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1 = staging.dbo.PLANTS.PLANT_CODE
WHERE  (CONVERT(DATETIME, dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40) > DATEADD(day, - 30, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY CONCAT(RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1), RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL6)),staging.dbo.ITEM_CODES.ITEM_CODE
```

Sample Table generated by query:
[image]

The end result that I am trying to achieve is the latest ITEM_CODE per unique LinkID Note the first and last rows in the table. The last row should not be pulled by the query.
How do I modify this query to make that happen?
I have tried various placements for DISTINCT and sub queries in the select and where statements.

Comment: Don't group by Item Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do in your case with `ROW_NUMBER` window function and `CTE`.

Solution can be like this:

```
WITH FilterCTE AS
(
    SELECT staging.dbo.ITEM_CODES.ITEM_CODE, MAX(dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40) AS SAMPLEDATE,
               CONCAT(RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1), RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL6)) AS LinkID,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CONCAT(RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1), RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL6)) ORDER BY MAX(dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40)) AS RowNumber
    FROM dbo.OC_VDATA 
        INNER JOIN dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX ON dbo.OC_VDATA.PARTNO = dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX AND dbo.OC_VDATA.DATETIME = dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.DATETIMEAUX 
        INNER JOIN stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES ON LEFT(dbo.OC_VDATA.PARTNO, 12) = staging.dbo.ITEM_CODES.SPEC_NO 
        AND LEFT(dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.PARTNOAUX, 12) = stagingPLM.dbo.ITEM_CODES.SPEC_NO 
        INNER JOIN stagingPLM.dbo.PLANTS ON dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1 = staging.dbo.PLANTS.PLANT_CODE
    WHERE  (CONVERT(DATETIME, dbo.OC_VDAT_AUX.UDL40) > DATEADD(day, - 30, GETDATE()))
    GROUP BY CONCAT(RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL1), RTRIM(dbo.OC_VDATA.UDL6)),staging.dbo.ITEM_CODES.ITEM_CODE
)
SELECT *
FROM FilterCTE
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: Awesome, Perfect just what I needed. I have never used the CTE and ROW_NUMBER before, but I certainly wish I had :-)